# Ethernet drops out on Ubuntu Server 18.04 using Realtek 8168

Tags: networking, 18.04, ethernet

for about a week now I have been experiencing problems with my Ubuntu Server 18.04 installation when I try to get it running as a router.

First and foremost, let me draw a simple diagram of my home network so you guys can better understand:

Internet <---> Modem/Router combo <---> My Ubuntu router <---> My devices via Ethernet

Now a question many of you may have is that why am I using two routers?
This is because for some odd reason my router will not let me port forward over 2 machines (possibly due to my ISP configuring the router beforehand), and also, I think it would be overall neater to have my own network subdivision because I have MANY devices.

Now to the problem:

Over the past week I have been trying to get my Ubuntu router working, but I have had no success. At first, everything works, and there are no issues, but about less than 5 minutes later, my Ubuntu router completely shuts off its internet connection randomly. It still has its IP addresses on both sides (private and public as shown on ifconfig), but cannot ping the gateway, DNS servers, or the internet. My suspicions point to my dual gigabit Realtek 8168 network card (as those are apparently notorious for issues), but i'm not quite sure. Any help would be appreciated!

Extra info:

Router specs:

- Intel Core 2 Duo E4400
- 4GB DDR2 RAM
- 320GB Hard Drive
- Rosewill RNG-407 dual gigabit network card (8168 chipset) + motherboard integrated Ethernet
- Integrated GPU

Router netplan config:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp3s0:
      gateway4: 192.168.0.1
      optional: true
      dhcp4: yes
    enp4s0:
      optional: true
      dhcp4: no
      addresses: [12.0.0.1/24]
```

Router /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf (I use isc-dhcp-server):

```
subnet 12.0.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
  option domain-name "myserver.ddns.net";
  option domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4;
  range 12.0.0.11 12.0.0.254;

  option broadcast-address 12.0.0.255;
  option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
  option routers 12.0.0.1;

  default-lease-time 600;
  max-lease-time 7200;

  ddns-update-style none;

  authoritative;
}
```

Router ifconfig (enp3s0 goes to main router, enp4s0 goes to my devices, and enp5s8 is a test network that is inactive) I have the router functions disabled as of now and it is only receiving internet from the main router via its onboard interface currently:

```
enp3s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet6 fe80::6a1c:a2ff:fe12:e11d  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 68:1c:a2:12:e1:1d  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 51  bytes 8279 (8.2 KB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 23  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 32  bytes 4160 (4.1 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
    device interrupt 24  base 0xd000

enp4s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 68:1c:a2:12:e1:1e  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 25  base 0x5000

enp5s8: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.25  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 2605:e000:9350:d700:21b:fcff:fe23:ace7  prefixlen 64  scopeid 
0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::21b:fcff:fe23:ace7  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:1b:fc:23:ac:e7  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 3477  bytes 332408 (332.4 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1262  bytes 157512 (157.5 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 942  bytes 59172 (59.1 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 942  bytes 59172 (59.1 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

tun0: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.8.0.1  netmask 255.255.255.255  destination 10.8.0.2
        inet6 fe80::cca1:384b:a42e:e483  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 
100  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 10  bytes 480 (480.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

I would be happy to provide more information on my system if required, and I thank anyone in advance for any help!

p.s. I know that there may be many posts about the problematic 8168 chipset, but unfortunately no solutions have worked for me.